# Matching an empty string with regex

Tags: regex

I've seen posts here on stackoverflow that say that the regex `^$` will match an empty string... So it made me think... why not something like this: `^\s+$` - does that not also work?  I know it's more typing, but it in my mind, it also makes more sense.  I've not used a whole lot of regex before, but it seems like my need for them is becoming greater as the days go by - so I'm taking the hint and attempting to learn.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> `^\s+$` - does that not also work?

Not for matching an empty string. In general, `X+` means `X` *one or more times*. So, `\s+` cannot match the empty string - it requires at least one `\s` in order to match.

```
                                     ^ \s + $
                                     | |  | |
start of string ---------------------+ |  | |
whitespace character ------------------+  | |
one or more of what precedes -------------+ |
end of string ------------------------------+
```

Now, `X*` means `X` *0 or more times*, so `^\s*$` would indeed match an empty string.

---

### `^\s+$`

[image]

### `^\s*$`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`^\s+$` will match a sequence of one or more whitespaces, which is not an empty string at all.

An empty string does not contain any character, not even whitespace. However, if you use `^\s*$`, it will match an empty string in addition to whitespaces.

Comment: "whitespace-only" is actually a quite useful category of strings :-)

Answer (score 2):

As others said, you probably mean `^\s*$`, not `^\s+$`, because `^\s+$` will fail to match the empty string, .

Whether `^\s*$` matches an empty string depends on your definition of "empty". Like `^$`, it will match the completely empty string . Unlike `^$`, it will also match a string consistening of only whitespace characters like spaces and tabs, such as    . Which is the "right" definition of "empty" depends on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

`\s` is the character class for whitespace. `^\s+$` would match both "\t\n" and "\t\t". They look empty, but are not. Spaces, tabs, and newlines are characters too! By using `^$`, you match the beginning of the string with `^` immediately followed by the end of the string `$`. Note that matching the regular expression `''` will also match empty strings, but match them anywhere.

Python example:

```
empty_string_matches = re.findall('', 'hello world')
empty_line_matches = re.findall('^$', 'hello world')
print "Matches for '':", empty_string_matches
print "Matches for '^$':", empty_line_matches
```

returns

```
Matches for '': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
Matches for '^$': []
```

Because there is an empty string between each letter in 'hello world'.

Answer (score 1):

`^\s+$` does NOT match an empty string. It matches a string of one or more whitespace symbols (spaces, tabs, linefeeds, etc.)