# What is a regex to match ONLY an empty string?

Tags: regex, string

There are lots of posts about regexs to match a *potentially* empty string, but I couldn't readily find any which provided a regex which *only* matched an empty string.

I know that `^` will match the beginning of any line and `$` will match the end of any line as well as the end of the string. As such, `/^$/` matches far more than the empty string such as "\n", "foobar\n\n", etc.

I would have thought, though, that `/\A\Z/` would match just the empty string, since `\A` matches the beginning of the string and `\Z` matches the end of the string. However, my testing shows that `/\A\Z/` will also match "\n". Why is that?

Comment: There are many [SO posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618634/matching-an-empty-string-with-regex) about regex to match an empty string, so at a cursory glance it seemed like it may be a duplicate. Consider changing your title to more specifically address your issue of ignoring line breaks.

Comment: That's a post about a regex which _doesn't_ match the empty string with a set of answers as to why. I really tried and couldn't find a post about a regex which only matched an empty string, let alone one which dealt with that and the difference between `\z` and `\Z`. I don't want to clutter up SO. If you can find a question this is a dup of, I'll gladly delete this one. That said, I added emphasis to the word ONLY in this title.

Comment: Remove the multiline flag and ^$ should work

Comment: @JamRisser I understand the interaction with multi-line mode. I should have been explicit, but I'm asking about a regex to match only an empty string _in multiline mode_. Note, in particular, the last paragraph.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It's as simple as the following. Many of the other answers aren't understood by the RE2 dialect used by C and golang.

```
^$
```

Comment: Do you disagree with the statement, included in the question: "As such, /^$/ matches far more than the empty string such as "\n", "foobar\n\n", etc."?

Comment: Yes I disagree with that statement. That statement is only true when the multiline flag is enabled.

Comment: And it probably wouldn't hurt to make sure the global flag is disabled, because it's not possible to have multiple instances of nothing.

Comment: Interesting, I'm curious about the use case

Comment: `r'^\Z'` and `r'\A\Z'` only match the empty string in **Python**. `r'^$'` matches `'\n'`: "By default ... `'$'` [matches] only at the end of the string [and immediately before the newline](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) (if any) at the end of the string."

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. At the JavaScript console `RegExp('^$').test('\n')` is `false` and `RegExp('^$').test('')` is `true`. The original poster must have had the multiline flag set to `true`. _i.e._ `RegExp('^$','m').test('\n')` equals `true`

Comment: This work perfect, at least in javascript as already mentioned. Also it's very easy to create a "should be empty or follow this rule. Made a simple date format check that looks like this.

/^(20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]|)$/.test('');
/^(20[0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]|)$/.test('2020-12-12');

Comment: This fails in Python 3.8. `re.match("^$", "\n")` returns a match object without the multiline flag being specified.

Answer (score 69):

I would use a negative lookahead for any character:

```
^(?![\s\S])
```

This can only match if the input is totally empty, because the character class will match any character, including any of the various newline characters.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `.` instead of `[\s\S]`?

Comment: @mbom you could if you enabled the DOTALL flag, so dot matches newlines too, but this way it works everywhere, even if flags aren't available.

Comment: This does not actually work, as it matches everything, _e.g._ at the JavaScript command line `RegExp('^(?![\s\S])').test('Hello World!')` returns `true`

Comment: @JonathanBenn This actually *does* work, if you execute it properly. In JavaScript console: `RegExp(/^(?![\s\S])/).test('') -> true`, and `RegExp(/^(?![\s\S])/).test('Hello World!') -> false`

Comment: @Bohemian You are right! I just learned something today... According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) the string expression requires double backslash. I should have used `RegExp('^(?![\\s\\S])')` or a literal as you did.

Answer (score 13):

As explained in http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html under the section "Strings Ending with a Line Break", `\Z` will generally match before the end of the last newline in strings that end in a newline. If you want to only match the end of the string, you need to use `\z`. The exception to this rule is Python.

In other words, to exclusively match an empty string, you need to use `/\A\z/`.

Comment: Tried this in Python 2.7.3 with re.match, doesn't appear to work. re.match("/\\A\\z/", "") returns None.

Comment: At JavaScript console `RegExp(/\A\z/).test('')` returns `false`

Answer (score 7):

^$ -- regex to accept empty string.And it wont match "/n" or "foobar/n" as you mentioned.
You could test this regex on https://www.regextester.com/1924.

If you have your existing regex use or(|) in your regex to match empty string.
For example
/^[A-Za-z0-9&._ ]+$|^$/

Answer (score 4):

Try looking here: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

I ran into the same problem you had though. I could only build a regex that would match only the empty string and also "\n". Try trimming/replacing the newline characters in the string with another character first.

I was using http://pythex.org/ and trying weird regexes like these:

`()`

`(?:)`

`^$`

`^(?:^\n){0}$`

and so on.

Answer (score 4):

I believe Python is the only widely used language that doesn't support `\z` in this way (yet). There are [Python bindings for Russ Cox / Google's super fast `re2` C++ library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/re2/) that can be "dropped in" as a replacement for the bundled `re`.

There's an excellent discussion (with workarounds) for this at [Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7063420/2019415), here on SO.

```
python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 16 2016, 01:14:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 3.4.1 on freebsd10
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re2 as re
>>> 
>>> re.match(r'\A\z', "")
<re2.Match object at 0x805d97170>
```

[@tchrist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7066413/2019415) is worth the read.

Answer (score 2):

The answer may be language dependent, but since you don't mention one, here is what I just came up with in js:

```
 var a = ['1','','2','','3'].join('\n');

 console.log(a.match(/^.{0}$/gm)); // ["", ""]

 // the "." is for readability. it doesn't really matter
 a.match(/^[you can put whatever the hell you want and this will also work just the same]{0}$/gm)
```

You could also do `a.match(/^(.{10,}|.{0})$/gm)` to match empty lines OR lines that meet a criteria.  (This is what I was looking for to end up here.)

> I know that ^ will match the beginning of any line and $ will match the end of any line

This is only true if you have the multiline flag turned on, otherwise it will only match the beginning/end of the string.  I'm assuming you know this and are implying that, but wanted to note it here for learners.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the most-approved answer, here is yet another way:

```
var result = !/[\d\D]/.test(string);  //[\d\D] will match any character
```

Comment: That's not a regex. That's a regex mixed with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bohemian and @mbomb007 mentioned before, this works AND has the additional advantage of being more readable:

`console.log(/^(?!.)/s.test("")); //true`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer considering also the case that an empty string might contain several whitespace characters for example spaces,tabs,line break characters
can be the folllowing pattern.

`pattern = r"^(\s*)$"`

This pattern matches if the string starts and ends with zero or more whitespace characters.

It was tested in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

You are not asking about the empty string. A string in regex is not a grouping of letters, numbers, and punctuation. It is a grouping of ASCII characters. So a "\n" is not an empty string. It has an ASCII character "\n" in it. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TOsMcgIK95k&list=PLbtzT1TYeoMjNOGEiaRmm_vMIwUAidnQz&index=1&ab_channel=hhp3hhp3)