# regexp to get words up next, exists or not

Tags: javascript

This regexp is matching strings after /ab. Also, i would like to match empty strings after /ab. How can i do that?. Thanks in advance.

```js
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');
const token = process.env.TOKEN;
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });

bot.onText(/\/ab (.+)/, (msg, match) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id
    const prompt = match[1]
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, prompt)
})
```

Comment: Can u please give an example of the search pattern

Comment: An empty string as in `.length` = 0? like ""?

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi for example if input is: '/ab'; prompt = '' (empty string), if input is: '/ab hello world'; prompt = 'hello world'

Comment: @zer00ne yes exactly

Comment: So the match is always nothing? Or is it everything after `/ab`? how would a guaranteed result of nothing be useful?

Comment: @zer00ne i need to get anything after /ab, words or empty strings

Comment: @sonEtLumiere IC, ok see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73272970/2813224).

Comment: @zer00ne this regexp is working --> /\/ab(.*)/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookbehind: `/^(?![\s\S])|(?<=\/ab).*/g`

A lookbehind `(?<=)` will match anything in front of it without being included in the actual match. <del>As for return an empty string, you'll need to explicitly return a "" if there's no match. You can change this line maybe:</del> Added an alternate [`^(?!\[\s\S\])|`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28652413/2813224)

```js
const rgx = new RegExp(/^(?![\s\S])|(?<=\/ab).*/, 'g');

const str = `/ab 1234 hdsso
/abksdfsioiowe
/ab
khbigigi7 
s366s7d /ab`;

let matches = [...str.matchAll(rgx)].flat();

console.log(matches);
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Wms0WT/2)

Comment: your answer is usefull but that regexp doesn't work as i expected

Comment: You want `/ab` included in the match?

Comment: no, only the words after /ab, also empty strings

Comment: @sonEtLumiere see update